# Using get inside lapply, inside a function

Tags: r, lapply

this may seem like a overly complicated question, but it has me driving me a little nuts for some time. It is also for curiosity, because I already have a way of doing what I need, so is not that important.

In R, I need a function to return a named list object with all the arguments and the values entered by the user. For this I have made this code (toy example):

```
foo <- function(a=1, b=5, h='coconut') {
    frm <- formals(foo)
    parms <- frm
    for (i in 1:length(frm))
        parms[[i]] <- get(names(frm)[i])
    return(parms)
}
```

So when this is asked:

```
> foo(b=0)

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 0

$h
[1] "coconut"
```

This result is perfect. The thing is, when I try to use `lapply` to the same goal, so as to be a little more efficient (and elegant), it does not work as I want it to:

```
foo <- function(a=1, b=5, h='coconut') {
    frm <- formals(foo)
    parms <- lapply(names(frm), get)
    names(parms) <- names(frm)
    return(parms)
}
```

The problem clearly is with the environment in which `get` evaluates it's first argument (a character string, the name of the variable). This I know in part from the error message:

```
> foo(b=0)
Error in FUN(c("a", "b", "h")[[1L]], ...) : object 'a' not found
```

and also, because when in the `.GlobalEnv` environment there are objects with the right names, foo returns their values instead:

```
> a <- 100
> b <- -1
> h <- 'wallnut'
> foo(b=0)
$a
[1] 100

$b
[1] -1

$h
[1] "wallnut"
```

Obviously, as `get` by default evaluates in the `parent.frame()`, it searches for the objects in the `.GlobalEnv` environment, instead of that of the current function. This is strange, since this does not happen with the first version of the function.

I have tried many options to make the function `get` to evaluate in the right environment, but could not do it correctly (I've tried `pos=-2,0,1,2` and `envir=NULL` as options).

If anyone happen to know a little more than me about environments, specially in this "strange" cases, I would love to know how to solve this.

Thanks for your time,

Juan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit of 2013-08-05**

Using `sapply()` instead of `lapply()`, simplifies this considerably:

```
foo4 <- function(a=1, b=5, h='coconut') {
    frm <- formals(sys.function())
    sapply(names(frm), get, envir=sys.frame(sys.parent(0)), simplify=FALSE)
}
foo4(b=0, h='mango')
```

This, though, without `sapply()` **or** `lapply()` might be the more elegant solution:

```
foo5 <- function(a=1, b=5, h='coconut') {
    modifyList(formals(sys.function()), as.list(match.call())[-1])
}
foo5(b=0, h='mango')
```

---

**Original post (2011-11-04)**

After casting about a bit, this looks to be the best solution.

```
foo <- function(a=1, b=5, h='coconut') {
    frm <- formals(foo)
    parms <- lapply(names(frm), get, envir=sys.frame(sys.parent(0)))
    names(parms) <- names(frm)
    return(parms)
}
foo(b=0, h='mango')
# $a
# [1] 1

# $b
# [1] 0

# $h
# [1] "mango"
```

There's some subtle stuff going on here with the way that `lapply` scopes/evaluates the calls that it constructs.  The details are hidden in a call to `.Internal(lapply(X, FUN))`, but for a taste, compare these two calls:

```
# With function matched by match.fun, search in sys.parent(0)
foo2 <- function(a=1, h='coconut') {
    lapply(names(formals()), 
           get, envir = sys.parent(0))
}

# With anonymous function, search in sys.parent(2)    
foo3 <- function(a=1, h='coconut') {
    lapply(names(formals()), 
           FUN = function(X) get(X, envir = sys.parent(2)))
}

foo4(a=0, h='mango')
foo5(a=0, h='mango')
```

Comment: ...even better if `foo2` and `foo3` got their own formals, and not `foo`'s :-)

Comment: To Josh: would it be the same if I use `envr=sys.parent() + 1`?

Comment: @Tommy -- it would be even better, wouldn't it.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I guess `frm <- formals()` is generally even better, but I'll leave it as is to highlight the single important difference.

Comment: @Juan -- You're right. `envir=sys.parent() + 1` works (and so does `envir=sys.parent(0)`).  Apparently the `envir` argument to `get` interprets integers as referring to the numbered frames on the calling stack (which you can examine with `sys.frames()`). The `sys.frame()` I put in `foo3` was thus totally unnecessary.

Comment: @Juan -- Thanks, by the way for the great original post. It drove me nuts too, for several hours there!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien thanks! It was just a problem that I bumped into. And by the way, the strategy used in the original `foo` function (the one with a `for` loop) has it's problems: whenever a default value is `NULL` problems arise...(e.g.: `foo <- function(a=NULL, b=2)`). This does not happen with the `lapply` versions.

Comment: Instead of `sys.frame(sys.parent(0))`, I think `environment()` is a bit more obvious.  In fact you could replace that entire line with `mget(names(frm), environment())`

Comment: Or you could replace the entire function with `as.list(environment())`

Answer (score 7):

Just convert the current environment into a list:

```
foo <- function(a=1, b=5, h='coconut') {
  as.list(environment())
}
foo(a = 0, h = 'mango')
```

Comment: Yes, cool, that's probably exactly what the OP was really after.

Answer (score 1):

This is adapted from @Josh O'Brien's solution above using `sapply` to automatically assign the correct names to the resulting list (saves one line of code):

```
foo <- function(a=1, b=5, h='coconut') {
    frm <- formals(foo)
    parms <- sapply(names(frm), get, envir=sys.frame(sys.parent(-1)), simplify=FALSE)
    return(parms)
}
```